# dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js wont work with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a dhtmlgoodies_calendar in my asp.net application and have made some changes to the writeCalendarContent method to disable the dates in the past. It works fine on Internet explorer. But in firefox and chrome the dates in the past are still displayed anyways.

Does anybody have any idea in how to make this work in those browers?
any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Here is my method:

```
       function writeCalendarContent()
{
    var blockDateInPast = true;
    var calendarContentDivExists = true;
    if(!calendarContentDiv){
        calendarContentDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
        calendarDiv.appendChild(calendarContentDiv);
        calendarContentDivExists = false;
    }
    currentMonth = currentMonth/1;
    var d = new Date();

    var data = new Date();

    var AnoAtual = data.getYear();
    var MesAtual = data.getMonth();
    var DiaAtual = data.getDate();

    d.setFullYear(currentYear);
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setMonth(currentMonth);

    var dayStartOfMonth = d.getDay();
    if (! weekStartsOnSunday) {
      if(dayStartOfMonth==0)dayStartOfMonth=7;
      dayStartOfMonth--;
   }

    document.getElementById('calendar_year_txt').innerHTML = currentYear;
    document.getElementById('calendar_month_txt').innerHTML = monthArray[currentMonth];
    document.getElementById('calendar_hour_txt').innerHTML = currentHour;
    document.getElementById('calendar_minute_txt').innerHTML = currentMinute;

    var existingTable = calendarContentDiv.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');
    if(existingTable.length>0){
        calendarContentDiv.removeChild(existingTable[0]);
    }

    var calTable = document.createElement('TABLE');
    calTable.width = '100%';
    calTable.cellSpacing = '0';
    calendarContentDiv.appendChild(calTable);




    var calTBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    calTable.appendChild(calTBody);
    var row = calTBody.insertRow(-1);
    row.className = 'calendar_week_row';
   if (showWeekNumber) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
       cell.innerHTML = weekString;
       cell.className = 'calendar_week_column';
       cell.style.backgroundColor = selectBoxRolloverBgColor;
    }

    for(var no=0;no<dayArray.length;no++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = dayArray[no];
    }

    var row = calTBody.insertRow(-1);

   if (showWeekNumber) {
       var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
       cell.className = 'calendar_week_column';
       cell.style.backgroundColor = selectBoxRolloverBgColor;
       var week = getWeek(currentYear,currentMonth,1);
       cell.innerHTML = week;       // Week
    }
    for(var no=0;no<dayStartOfMonth;no++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }

    var colCounter = dayStartOfMonth;
    var daysInMonth = daysInMonthArray[currentMonth];
    if(daysInMonth==28){
        if(isLeapYear(currentYear))daysInMonth=29;
    }

    for(var no=1;no<=daysInMonth;no++){
        d.setDate(no-1);
        if(colCounter>0 && colCounter%7==0){
            var row = calTBody.insertRow(-1);
         if (showWeekNumber) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.className = 'calendar_week_column';
            var week = getWeek(currentYear,currentMonth,no);
            cell.innerHTML = week;      // Week
            cell.style.backgroundColor = selectBoxRolloverBgColor;
         }
        }
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);


            if (currentYear<AnoAtual && blockDateInPast==true)
            {
               cell.className='DesactiveDay';
               cell.onclick = null;

            }
            else if (currentYear==AnoAtual)
            {
                if (currentMonth < MesAtual && blockDateInPast == true)
                {
                 cell.className='DesactiveDay';
                  cell.onclick = null;
                }
                else if (currentMonth==MesAtual)
                {
                    if (no < DiaAtual && blockDateInPast == true)
                    {
                     cell.className='DesactiveDay';
                      cell.onclick = null;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     cell.onclick = pickDate;

                     }

                }
                else
                {
                 cell.onclick = pickDate;
                }

            }
            else
            {
            cell.onclick = pickDate;
            }

        if (cell.onclick == pickDate)
        {
        if(currentYear==inputYear && currentMonth == inputMonth && no==inputDay){
            cell.className='activeDay';
            cell.onclick = pickDate;
        }
        }
        cell.innerHTML = no;

        colCounter++;
    }


    if(!document.all){
        if(calendarContentDiv.offsetHeight)
            document.getElementById('topBar').style.top = calendarContentDiv.offsetHeight + document.getElementById('timeBar').offsetHeight + document.getElementById('topBar').offsetHeight -1 + 'px';
        else{
            document.getElementById('topBar').style.top = '';
            document.getElementById('topBar').style.bottom = '0px';
        }

    }

    if(iframeObj){
        if(!calendarContentDivExists)setTimeout('resizeIframe()',350);else setTimeout('resizeIframe()',10);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add following code at the end of `writeCalendarContent()`,

```
 if(currentYear==inputYear && currentMonth == inputMonth && no==inputDay){
    cell.className='activeDay';
    cell.onclick = pickDate;
 }
 else if(currentYear<inputYear || currentMonth < inputMonth || no<inputDay){
    cell.className = 'inactive-date';
 }
 else{
    cell.onclick = pickDate;
 }
 cell.innerHTML = no;
 colCounter++;
```

It adds the click event only for current date and next dates. It doesn't add click for past dates. You can add style for past dates(add style for inactive-date class).

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, this following code is correct and tested

```
if(disabledDateInPast){
        var now = new Date();
        var yearOfNow = now.getFullYear();
        var monthOfNow = now.getMonth();
        var noOfNow = now.getDate();

        if(currentYear < yearOfNow){
            cell.className = 'desactiveDay';
        }
        else if(currentYear > yearOfNow){
            cell.onclick = pickDate;
        }
        else if (currentYear == yearOfNow){
            if(currentMonth < monthOfNow){
                cell.className = 'desactiveDay';
            }
            else if(currentMonth > monthOfNow){
                cell.onclick = pickDate;
            }
            else if(currentMonth == monthOfNow){
                if(no < noOfNow){
                cell.className = 'desactiveDay';
                }
                else{
                    cell.onclick = pickDate;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.onclick = pickDate;
    }

    if(currentYear==inputYear && currentMonth == inputMonth && no==inputDay){
        cell.className='activeDay';
    }
```